# Fusioncharts Getting Started Guide page remains empty

Tags: python, django, fusioncharts

I have just installed FusionCharts Suite XT v3.13.4 to use in my (Python) Django application. I have done the Getting Started Guide (https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/django/your-first-chart-using-django#installation-2), but I can't seem to get it to work. I don't get an error, but my page remains completely empty. I don't know what I did wrong, I followed the tutorial exactly.

dash.html

```
<!-- Filename: app_name/templates/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>FC-python wrapper</title>
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js" %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="myFirstchart-container">{{ output|safe }}</div>
</body>

</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


from collections import OrderedDict

# Include the `fusioncharts.py` file that contains functions to embed the charts.
#from fusioncharts import FusionCharts
from vsdk.dashboard.fusioncharts import FusionCharts

def myFirstChart(request):

    #Chart data is passed to the `dataSource` parameter, like a dictionary in the form of key-value pairs.
    dataSource = OrderedDict()

    # The `chartConfig` dict contains key-value pairs of data for chart attribute
    chartConfig = OrderedDict()
    chartConfig['caption'] = 'Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]'
    chartConfig['subCaption'] = 'In MMbbl = One Million barrels'
    chartConfig['xAxisName'] = 'Country'
    chartConfig['yAxisName'] = 'Reserves (MMbbl)'
    chartConfig['numberSuffix'] = 'K'
    chartConfig['theme'] = 'fusion'

    # The `chartData` dict contains key-value pairs of data
    chartData = OrderedDict()
    chartData['Venezuela'] = 290
    chartData['Saudi'] = 260
    chartData['Canada'] = 180
    chartData['Iran'] = 140
    chartData['Russia'] = 115
    chartData['UAE'] = 100
    chartData['US'] = 30
    chartData['China'] = 30

    dataSource['chart'] = chartConfig
    dataSource['data'] = []

    # Convert the data in the `chartData`array into a format that can be consumed by FusionCharts.
    #The data for the chart should be in an array wherein each element of the array
    #is a JSON object# having the `label` and `value` as keys.

    #Iterate through the data in `chartData` and insert into the `dataSource['data']` list.
    for key, value in chartData.items():
        data = {}
    data['label'] = key
    data['value'] = value
    dataSource['data'].append(data)


# Create an object for the column 2D chart using the FusionCharts class constructor
# The chart data is passed to the `dataSource` parameter.
    column2D = FusionCharts("column2d", "ex1" , "600", "400", "chart-1", "json", dataSource)

    return  render(request, 'dash.html', {'output' : column2D.render(), 'chartTitle': 'Simple Chart Using Array'})
```

urls.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import path

from vsdk.dashboard.fusioncharts import FusionCharts
from . import views

from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.myFirstChart, name = 'demo'),
]
```

Comment: the div container id is not matching with the id that you have passed to the fusioncharts constructor in views.py, please set myFirstchart-container instead of chart-1

Here is the snippet :




column2D = FusionCharts("column2d", "ex1" , "600", "400", "myFirstchart-container", "json", dataSource)

Comment: Thank you! I did discover some more errors in my code, but this definitely did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in the "Getting Started Guide" are a bit confusion and there are some errors. Here is my working version of the Fusionchart example.

### Fusionchart example

You can use FusionCharts to render charts in html. I have based the example on the [Getting Started Guide](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/django/your-first-chart-using-django) and tweaked here and there to make it work. To replicate just do the following:

copy my github code, this will create an new project directory `fusionchart_example`.

```
git clone https://github.com/bvermeulen/fusionchart_example
```

The tree structure should look like:

[image]

go to this folder and create a virtual environment for Django, note I work with Python 3.6.8, but likely other python 3.6 or 3.7 would work ok as well.

```
python -m venv ./venv
```

activate the environment (Linux)

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

(or Windows)

```
./venv/scripts/activate
```

with the virtual environment enabled install Django

```
pip install django==2.2.3
```

You can now run the app

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and view the result in your browser at `127.0.0.1:8000` that should look like:

[image]

You can review the source code when you have cloned my github, especially `settings.py`, but I give `urls.py`,  `views.py` and `chart.html` below as first reference.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from render_graph import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.chart, name='chart'),

]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from collections import OrderedDict

# Include the `fusioncharts.py` file that contains functions to embed the charts.
from fusioncharts import FusionCharts
from pprint import pprint

def chart(request):

    #Chart data is passed to the `dataSource` parameter, like a dictionary in the form of key-value pairs.
    dataSource = OrderedDict()

    # The `chartConfig` dict contains key-value pairs of data for chart attribute
    chartConfig = OrderedDict()
    chartConfig["caption"] = "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]"
    chartConfig["subCaption"] = "In MMbbl = One Million barrels"
    chartConfig["xAxisName"] = "Country"
    chartConfig["yAxisName"] = "Reserves (MMbbl)"
    chartConfig["numberSuffix"] = "K"
    chartConfig["theme"] = "fusion"

    # The `chartData` dict contains key-value pairs of data
    chartData = OrderedDict()
    chartData["Venezuela"] = 290
    chartData["Saudi"] = 260
    chartData["Canada"] = 180
    chartData["Iran"] = 140
    chartData["Russia"] = 115
    chartData["UAE"] = 100
    chartData["US"] = 30
    chartData["China"] = 30

    dataSource["chart"] = chartConfig
    dataSource["data"] = []

    # Convert the data in the `chartData`array into a format that can be consumed by FusionCharts.
    #The data for the chart should be in an array wherein each element of the array
    #is a JSON object# having the `label` and `value` as keys.

    #Iterate through the data in `chartData` and insert into the `dataSource['data']` list.
    for key, value in chartData.items():
        dataSource["data"].append({'label':key, 'value': value})

    # print the datasource to see what will be rendered
    pprint(dataSource)

    # Create an object for the column 2D chart using the FusionCharts class constructor
    # The chart data is passed to the `dataSource` parameter.
    column2D = FusionCharts("column2d", "Oil_Reserves", "600", "400", "Oil_Reserves-container", "json", dataSource)

    context = {'output': column2D.render(), }

    return render(request, 'chart.html', context)
```

chart.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Oil Reserves</title>
    {% load static %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'fusioncharts/types/fusioncharts.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js' %}"></script>

  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="Oil_Reserves-container">{{ output|safe }}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Fusioncharts says this is a trial version, so better check if any costs are involved. Let me know if you need any more info. Good luck...

Bruno Vermeulen
bruno.vermeulen@hotmail.com
8 July 2019